# Can I use facetime in my own iOS app to measure call duration between two users?

Tags: ios, videochat, facetime

I want to implement a functionality where users of my app can call each other on iOS. A convenient way would be using the built-in facetime. 
Is there a way how I can take the time the call lasted?

For example:

1. Alice calls Bob.
2. Bob takes call and timer starts
3. As soon as the call is ended, the timer stops.

Can this be implemented using facetime?

Comment: Technically, `applicationWillResignActive` is called in the AppDelegate once a call comes in and `applicationDidBecomeActive` is called when the app becomes active again, so your call has ended. However, you can't be sure that both of those were triggered by a call, and so this approach is *highly* error-prone, yet the only one you'll be able to use at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can only initiate facetime calls (using the `facetime://` URL scheme). There is no way to know if the call went through, and if it did, how long it took.

In short: No.